# VS10 Additional library directories fails when using a relative path

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I set up my project with relative paths, it fails.

// Does not work
properties-linker-general-additional library directories

```
..\..\libraries
```

// works fine

```
C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\project\libraries
```

How do I get the relative paths to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making it relative to your project directory or solution directory (as appropriate). I avoid playing guessing games with my current directory. Use the convenient variables defined by Visual Studio to avoid hard coding a path.

```
$(ProjectDir)\..\..\libraries
```

or

```
$(SolutionDir)\..\..\libraries
```

Comment: This works but there seems to be a strange bug. When typing out the path, visual studio helps you with the path, however this path was wrong for me. navigating using the visual studio drop-down hints gave: $(SolutionDir)\..\..\..\libraries which did not work, but $(SolutionDir)\..\..\libraries did.

Comment: I have the same problem of the comment above. This seems to be a VS bug