# C++ Additional Includes VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

So I have a structure like below.  (Similar to bigger project I'm really working on)
`tryWithNewLib\testProject\testProject\testProject.vcxprog`
`tryWithNewLib\testProject\testProject.sln`

I have this open source library I want to use.
`tryWithNewLib\XERCESCPKG-31-VC100\include\xercesc\util`

Additional Include Directories:
`D:\tryWithNewLib\XERCESCPKG-31-VC100\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

I am expecting this to work:

```
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks I was trying to fix that of course I would only notice after posting and not in preview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537261/vs10-additional-library-directories-fails-when-using-a-relative-path?answertab=active#tab-top I have tried using $(SolutionDir)\..\ like was shown in the answer there and I end up C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue may have been that I was updating Additional include Directories for the wrong configuration.  (I've changed a million things so I'm not sure this is really the fix).